# name value in asp:Textbox

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" name={@Computer} id="ff1{$Pos}" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Text','TextChanged','',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string('')),'@Computer')}" />
```

I click on a link, example: "example.aspx?Computer=z".
On the example page I want a textbox with the value z.

{@Computer} doesn't work, how do I work this out?

Comment: i think you need to explain better what you want doing! sorry couldnt get much out of what you want! appart from getting a textbox text that displays z?

Answer (score 1):

ahhhhhh lol i get you ;)

so on a seprate page you have a link, the link as your example you gave is:

```
example.aspx?Computer=z
```

now on that aspx page you have a textbox and you want to pull out the value z from the varible Computer from the url right?

use `Request.QueryString` to get the value:

in codebehind its:

```
string ComputerID = Request.QueryString["Computer"];
TextBox t = new TextBox();
T.Text = ComputerID
this.Controls.Add(T)
```

for aspx page do:

I think it goes like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# request.querystring("Computer") %>'/>
```

**EDIT**

went to edit your question and realised that the code wasnt in a codeblock, now its more readable but i guessed it the first time round tho:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" name='<%# request.querystring("Computer") %>' id="ff1{$Pos}" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Text','TextChanged','',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string('')),'<%# request.querystring("Computer") %>')}" />
```

that should work,....I think ;)